# Where and when do we light Shabbos candles 15 minutes later than usual?

Tags: minhag, riddle, shabbat

Where and when do we light Shabbos candles 15 minutes later than usual?

Comment: at my house, in the winter, when my wife walks in the door 3 mins before shekiya

Answer (score 4):

The Minhag Yerushalyim is to light candles Erev Shabbos 40 minutes prior to Shekiya. On Erev Shabbos Chanuka many people in Yerushalyim light the Menora 25 minutes prior to Shekiya and then the Shabbos candles.